# Error validating client secret. OAuthException

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook authenticator (for an app on fb, not website access) but receive this error : "Error validating client secret. OAuthException".

this is a part of code :

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    if(empty($code)){
        $dialog_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
            ."access_token?"
            ."client_id=".$fbconfig['appid']
            ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($args['redirect_uri'])
            ."&scope=publish_stream,email";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$dialog_url';</script>";
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo "AAA";
    }else{
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
            ."access_token?"
            ."client_id=".$fbconfig['appid']
            ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($args['redirect_uri'])
            ."&client_secret=". $fbconfig['secret']
            ."&code=".$args['scope'];
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];
        echo "aaaaaaaaaaa";
    }
}else{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
    echo $loginUrl;
    echo "<b>Attendere caricamento di permessi da richiedere all'utente...</b>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit();
}
```

why i get this error ?
App_id and secret_id are correct.
what is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to handle exchanging the code for a token on your own? The PHP SDK is perfectly capable of doing that itself.

Comment: i didn't know this..i want only create an authenticator for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Copy correctly the app secret. The last piece could be hidden in a second line
[App dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpkzK.png)